# Embedding an attachment from a stream

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Currently we are attaching a file to a Lotus Document with the following code:

```
final RichTextItem rtitem = document.createRichTextItem(referenceName);

final int type = EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT;
final String clazz = null;
final String source = file.getFileName();
rtitem.embedObject(type, clazz, source, name);

document.save();
```

Unfortunately the `source` parameter of the `embedObject` method has to be a path of a file in the file system. Is it possible to embed an object from a stream somehow? The embeddable content currently is in the memory, so it's not too efficient (and clean) to write it out to a file and let the Lotus API to read it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rtitem class only can attach files, not streams. However you can use MIME and the Lotus MimeEntry classes to create an attachment from anything that you can read. This LotusScript [code sample](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/discussion.xsp?documentId=8C1C6EA6706D64178625723F00574260&action=openDocument) should give you all you need to get started. The API is the same for Java. Let us know how it works for you.

Comment: Other than MIME, I have not found any other viable way to do this either. +1